# How to insert UIButton through code with AutoLayout feature enabled - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, autolayout

I have been trying to insert a UIButton programatically, as I am using Autolayout I have done something like that...

```
[self.add_scroll_view addConstraints : [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat : @"V:[date_picker_btn]-[button(==date_picker_btn)]"
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(date_picker_btn, button)]];
```

I have two questions here...

i) Button inserted is not the same width as date_picker_btn even though I mentioned button(==date_picker_btn).

ii) I have inserted properely, however below views should align accordingly down to accommodate new button... How to do that...

Thanx

Comment: As a quick recommendation, take a look at KeepLayout Library (https://github.com/iMartinKiss/KeepLayout), solves this kind of problems quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first question I have mentioned V: so it means (==) will assign height not width. To set width it should start with H:.

Next question, To insert a button between two existing button need to handle already existing constraints, here above I have added new constraints only not handle old existing, so I have to delete the existing constraints, so that it avoid conflicts. Works fine.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

When using the visual format language, the superview of the view for which the constraint is being described is represented by the | character.

Example:

V:|-20-[mybutton1(>=70@500)]-[mybutton2(==mybutton1)]-30-[mybutton3]-|

[Refer this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_the_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Visual_Format_Language)

Comment: I will check that, any idea about inserting new button and how to handle the below views?

Comment: you can handle base on super view but if you do all handling stuff in scrollview than your Constraints for subviews in scroll views don't work like constraints in other views. They're used to set the contentSize of the scroll view. That way, you throw a bunch of stuff on a scroll view, set the constraints for the stuff inside it, and the contentSize is calculated for you. It's very cool feature, but it's antithetical to what you're trying to do here.